# Finding the output by setting a criteria in R?

Tags: r, function, math, linear-algebra, algebra

For a set of input (*see below*), when I run the following R code, I get two answers stored in `ncp`. Now suppose I want the difference between the two answers in `ncp` (i.e., `abs(ncp[2] - ncp[1])`) to be `1.4`.

In such a case, is it possible to instead solve for the smallest possible `df` (currently `df` is in the input)?

```
alpha = c(.025, .975);  df = 29;  q = 3   # The input

f <- function(ncp, alpha, q, df){     # Notice `ncp` is the unknown
 alpha - suppressWarnings(pt(q, df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) # The function
 }

ncp <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),     # Root finding: finds `ncp`
     function(x) uniroot(f, c(-q, q+15), alpha = x, q = q, df = df)[[1]])
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: first, ddd does not run. also are yu trying to solve for df, with fixed alpha, and q?

Comment: but what is ddd solving??

Comment: mhh not really, does the alpha vector  change? does the q value change? or just alpha and q value are constant and find df to give ncp difference be 0.4?

Comment: That is clear.. but there is no such `df`... with infinity degrees of freedom, the absolute difference is `0.7156824` so there is no such df that can make the difference be 0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are taking all the rest to be constant, then we can write a function `ncp` which just takes an argument `df`

```
ncp=function(df){
  sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),     # Root finding
         function(x) uniroot(f, c(-q, q+15), alpha = x, q = q, df = df)[[1]]/sqrt(30))
}

ncp(29)
[1] 0.1592547 0.9280011
```

After this you can write a function that takes the absolute difference of the ncp values, and we will subtract

```
m=function(df,y=0){
  abs(abs(diff(ncp(df)))-y)
}
```

in short, `m(df,0)` gives the absolute difference compared to zero. while `m(df,0.4)` will be the absolute difference of the ncp values - 0.4. Our aim is to minimize this absolute value difference and y. I will elaborate on this.

On minimizing the m function with a respective y value:

For example, lets try to find a `df` whith all the rest (alpha, and q) kept constant such that the absolute difference of ncp values is 1:

```
(a=optimise(m,c(1,100000),y=1))#default for minimization ie maximum=FALSE
$`minimum`
[1] 4.415955

$objective
[1] 3.798379e-08
```

The objective value is 0 so we did find the correct df value since we were minimizing.

```
ncp(a$minimum)
[1] 0.03385211 1.03385215
```

From the ncp values above, yu can tell that indeed the difference between the two values is 1. Thus df=4.415955 will give us ncp absolute difference of 1 with the above alpha and q values

```
b=ncp(a$minimum)
abs(b[2]-b[1])
[1] 1
```

so I can also do:

```
m(a$minimum)
[1] 1
```

I tend to believe it is clear now what y stands for as an argument of `m`.

Now to find the difference of 0.4, we just do the same thing:

```
 optimise(m,c(1,1000000),y=0.4,maximum = F)
$`minimum`
[1] 1e+06

$objective
[1] 0.315684
```

As for this one, we see that the objective value is not zero, so we did not converge. Even if we were to increase our range, the objective wont change. Meaning that the smallest difference is the `objective(0.315684) +0.4 =0.715684`.. That is the smallenst absolute difference for the ncp values with this alpha and q. ie

```
m(Inf)
[1] 0.7156824
```

So we cant have an absolute difference of 0.4, but if we change alpha and q, we will do get an absolute difference of 0.4

For all values oy `y` such that `m(Inf)<y<m(1)`, we will do get a df that will satisfy the condition

Comment: @rnorouzian after running all the above, you can wrap them as: `my.opt=function(y){
  s=optimise(m,c(1,100000),y=y,maximum = F);
if(round(s$objective,5)!=0)return(NA);
  s[[1]]
}; my.opt(0.4);my.opt(1)`

Comment: @rnorouzian there is no need to run it.. you really do not need it.. only that you said you needed to wrap everything together, although you do not need it.

Comment: @rnorouzian Please don't ping users asking them to look at your new questions

Comment: @rnorouzian which question?

Comment: on the question you deleted: on the other hand, the upper value that is with alpha=0.95, the ncp value will be `14.29458`. so if you do `pf(2,3,108,14.29458,lower.tail = F)` you should get 0.95 back